# SQL Return Column value as Enum - GetValue() field from another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, enumeration

Here are the two tables;

Cathegories

```
----------------------------------------
Cathegory (tinyint)  |  Name (nvarchar)
----------------------------------------
0                    |  Field
1                    |  Mountain
2                    |  River
----------------------------------------
```

Places

```
------------------------------------------
Name (nvarchar)      |  Cathegory(tinyint)
------------------------------------------
Abc                  |  2
Xyz                  |  1
------------------------------------------
```

When I want to retrieve the Places listing Names and their Cathegories not in the int format but according to the description in Cathegories.

So retrieving Abc I want it like this;

"River" instead the '2'

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/) - but this looks like a simple JOIN between the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join two table on `cathegory` as shown below.

```
select
    p.name as places,
    c.name as category_name
from places p
join cathegories c
on p.cathegory = c.cathegory
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Initially thought the variables places and category_names are the actual column names but I got it

Answer (score 2):

Please use below query,

```
select c.name as place, p.name as name from Cathegories c
inner join Places p
on (c.Cathegory  = p.Cathegory);
```

Comment: Can explain, why down vote even if it is a correct answer?

Comment: someone may thought it just copy pasted of above answer. just upvoted it. :)

Comment: oh oh, even yours is a correct answer, will upvote you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of multiple JOIN statements based on the accepted answer:

```
SELECT 

ColumnUserViews,

C.Cathegory AS VCathegory, 

ColumnUserPoints, 

T.Description AS VTag1,
TT.Description AS VTag2


FROM dbo.Users U

JOIN dbo.Cathegories C ON U.Cathegory = C.Cathegory
JOIN dbo.Tags T ON U.Tag1 = T.Tag
JOIN dbo.Tags TT ON U.Tag2 = TT.Tag
```

The keyword U defines physical table Users, T Tags, and TT also Tags (free to rename).
VCathegory is a new virtual Column to be retrieved which holds the value of Users.Cathegory translated into Cathegories.Description ('s string equivalent) as per this current scheme.